# Batch merging field mapping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, merge

I made the following script to merge shape files of different format types (poly,line, points):

```
def main():    
    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env
    import globalpath
    import os
    env.workspace = globalpath.toolDataPath
    dataPath=globalpath.toolDataPath
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


    #try:
    DataTypeL=[("Polygon","mergedTOTPoly.shp"),("Polyline","mergedTOTLines.shp"),("Point","MergedTOTPoint.shp")]

    for dType in DataTypeL:
        (Typei,Title)=dType
        matches = []
        counter=0

        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(dataPath+"\\UtilityDataFromZorgel",datatype="FeatureClass",type=Typei):
            for filename in filenames:       
                match = ( os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
                arcpy.AddMessage(m)
                matches.append (match)
                counter = counter + 1 
        arcpy.Merge_management(matches, dataPath+"\\utilities"+Title)
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(counter)+" "+str(Typei)+" layers were merged into "+ str(filename))
    #except:
    arcpy.AddWarning("Merging Utility Layers Failed")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\merger.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\merger.py", line 25, in main
    arcpy.Merge_management(matches, dataPath+"\\utilities"+Title)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3762, in Merge
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 001156: Failed on input OID 0, could not write value 'Kanata' to output field TILE_ID
Failed to execute (Merge).
```

When I merge these files manually from arcmap it works, and fields are mapped as follows:

"STRUCT_TYP \"STRUCT_TYP\" true true false 18 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Allstream_hdwr_L,STRUCT_TYP,-1,-1,allstream_L,STRUCT_TYP,-1,-1,Allstream_lines_L,STRUCT_TYP,-1,-1,Allstream_text_L,STRUCT_TYP,-1,-1,Atria_lines_L,STRUCT_TYP,-1,-1,Atria_text_L,STRUCT_TYP,-1,-1,bell_L,STRUCT_TYP,-1,-1)

where STRUCT_TYP is a shared field.

please let me know how can I get around this error, and if it is indeed mapping the fields how can I do it in batched merging, or should I merge each file individually?

Comment: Take a deep look into this online topic: [Mapping input fields to output fields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z00000014000000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to run on a directory full of parcels, PLSS, and annexations. The directory had a mix of shapefiles and file geodatabases. I defined the datapath differently, but otherwise changed nothing.

It failed on the 13th polygon feature class. The resulting shapefile had 62 fields and 44525 records. My failure was a type mismatch, so it was different than yours.

Try running on a subset of your input feature classes and add some print commands to tell you which feature class failed. You may have a field name or file name that is invalid in arcpy, but works when the feature class is inserted as a layer in ArcMap.

Comment: I'll try that and post what I find

Comment: and why did you get a type mismatch at that point I'm curious

Comment: adding error handlers shows that only polygons are giving me errors, i removed some of the shape files to see if the issue persists it appears that "TILE_ID" is a problematic field as the problem appears with different values other than "Kanata"

Comment: Is the "TILE_ID" field the same length (in characters) in all of your source files? If not, then rename one of your files with a wider "TILE_ID" field so that it is processed first.

Comment: no it's not the same length, I could have swore its about text length, i was trying to recalculate the value for "TILE_ID" as str(!TILE_ID!)[:4]

Comment: By the way, my type mismatch error was coming from your last AddMessage. I was running your script from Idle, and I neglected to replace AddMessage with print (Doh!). Your script ran perfectly for me after I did that.

Comment: thanks for your feedback @jlcrawf0, I have edited my addmessage. you're suggestion of renaming the files works, thats good for now. but I feel uneasy having to do that manually before running the script I feel my work is undone! knowing the problem is a big step thanks to you.