# How does GIS detect the error causing field in "ExecuteError: ERROR 001156"

Tags: arcpy, merge, error-001156

I always get all types of errors, and would like to know if i can use the information in these error messages generated by arcpy to fix the issue and repeat the step where it occurred.

for example in batch merging:

```
   layerList[shp1,shp2,shp3,shp4]
   arcpy.Merge_management(layerList,"C:\\Data\\title.shp")
```

and I get the following error:

```
   ExecuteError: ERROR 001156: Failed on input OID 0, could not write value 'Kanata' to output field ErrorCuasingField
Failed to execute (Merge).
```

How can I get the ErrorCausingField in my script, so i can maybe delete it before repeating the merging process.

Also I have a another question addressing this issue specifically: ([Batch merging field mapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147839/batch-merging-field-mapping/147850#147850)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a call to get the traceback object to your previous script  [(Batch merging field mapping)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147839/batch-merging-field-mapping/147850#147850). I added a shapefile with an "Acres" field that was one character wide, and got this traceback message:
ERROR 001156: Failed on input OID 0, could not write value '340.417' to output field Acres

My working version of your script, set up to run in Idle, is below.

```
import arcpy, sys, os, traceback
dataPath=r"C:\workspace\weld county\parcels"
try:
    DataTypeL=[("Polygon","mergedTOTPoly.shp"),("Polyline","mergedTOTLines.shp"),("Point","MergedTOTPoint.shp")]

    for dType in DataTypeL:
        (Typei,Title)=dType
        matches = []
        counter=0

        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(dataPath,datatype="FeatureClass",type=Typei):
            for filename in filenames:
                print filename
                match = ( os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
                #arcpy.AddMessage(m)
                matches.append (match)
                counter = counter + 1 
        arcpy.Merge_management(matches, dataPath+"\\utilities"+Title)
        print counter
        print Typei
        #arcpy.AddMessage(counter+" "+Typei+" layers were merged into "+ filename)
except arcpy.ExecuteError: 
    # Get the tool error messages 
    # 
    msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2) 

    # Return tool error messages for use with a script tool 
    #
    arcpy.AddError(msgs) 

    # Print tool error messages for use in Python/PythonWin 
    # 
    print msgs

except:
    # Get the traceback object
    #
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]

    # Concatenate information together concerning the error into a message string
    #
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    msgs = "ArcPy ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"

    # Return python error messages for use in script tool or Python Window
    #
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)

    # Print Python error messages for use in Python / Python Window
    #
    print pymsg + "\n"
    print msgs
```

Comment: I'll try playing around with GetMessages, I can isolate the the field title if I know what the error message is, since I know it's position in the sentence (either from left or from right) in this case it's conveniently at the end.spaces should be useful in this case. thanks for information.